# Own property layer, default values for extrusion, duplicating, etc

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an unique identifier per face like so:

```
l_face_id = l_bm.faces.layers.int.new('id')
```

The problem comes when extruding or duplicating the faces, since the IDs gets duplicated.
I saw there was this reported to implement and option to set the values to a default one when this happens:

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/42865

It seems, this was never implemented, but in one of the comments someone mentions there is a "set_default" callback already, but I cannot find any documentation about it.

I have tried to set it like this:

```
l_face_id = l_bm.faces.layers.int.new(name='id', set=cb_set)
```

But I got this error:
**TypeError: new() takes no keyword arguments**

Any idea how I can set a default value for cases like extruding? Or, if there is any other way I could create a unique identifier for faces that doesn't change when other faces get deleted or added?